# Moving bin to the end of the dock in 19.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 19.10, ubuntu-dock

I'm trying to make my desktop look just a bit more like Unity and I'm wondering in 19.10 if there is a way to move the bin right down to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: it requires modification of gnome-shell-extension `ubuntu-dock` which is located at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com`. IMHO developers of this extension or experts who can write gnome-shell-extensions can only do this.

Comment: it tells me in Tweaks

"This a mock extension. It does nothing if installed from extensions.gnome.org. Please use dash to dock which provides the same functionalities with different defaults. This name is used to protect and reserve the name for ubuntu dock, available as a system extension on ubuntu. This allow us to not trump updates outside of our QA process via an external upload."